# request.getSession(false) not detecting previous Session

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, httprequest

I have three different servers running Tomcat 7. I'm using JDK 7 and Spring framework.

On my development and Production environment, everything is working smoothly, however on the third machine, I'm encountering an issue with detecting sessions.

On the third server, the initial page opens up fine but the following line of code returns null.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/getCaptcha",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody OutputStream getCaptchaImage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

    String stToken = request.getParameter("token");
    OutputStream os = null;

    try{
        HttpSession httpsession = request.getSession(false);
        System.out.println("HttpSession: "+httpsession);
        if(httpsession != null){
            ...
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return os;
}
```

Here HttpSession is null and it cannot detect the session I previously set with

```
    HttpSession httpsession = request.getSession(true);
```

Aside from this, in my entire project the request.getSession(false) is returning null even though the session was previously set.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something since the same code is working perfectly on the other two servers. Any help/guidance/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just try request.getSession() to fetch session.

Comment: @user1211 request.getSession() will create a new session if no session exists. This is not what he asking.

Comment: @Chinmay is correct, I'm trying to get my existing session.

Comment: Did you check the configuration of the three Tomcat's is the same?

Comment: @jlumietu   Is there a particular setting I should be look for?

Comment: @DhruvPant I would start checking the properties of the session cookie. As you have two environments where the app runs properly, and only one where happens the problem, compare de JSESSIONID cookie from both 3 servers. Check the domains, the paths are the same, the expires setting. On the tomcat where happens the error, you might see that the cookie value changes on each request. Do you have any web server (Apache, IIS) running as frontend or balancer for the Tomcats?

Comment: @jlumietu I have a balancer on two servers but everything works fine, the one server which has the problem is not connected to the balancer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare HTTP session in request method of Spring MVC

```
@RequestMapping("/signup")
public void handleMyRequest(HttpSession session, ...) {
   ...
}
```

Not sure, whether it fits into your requirements or not. I did it for my project.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have not yet tried the solution you suggested but my project is already huge with thousands of methods, replacing each method's signature is not a feasible solution. I'm trying to figure out what configuration/setting I'm missing on the third server that is preventing the same code to be executed correctly which is working correctly on the first two servers.